# Git workflow: leave or keep an old code?

Tags: git, workflow

We are a small team of data scientists maintaining some business processes in Git repository.

We have a lot of dead and unused code, things like `process.R`, `process_1_1_0.R` and `process2.R` (and, obviously, only one is used).
The idea has always been to keep some older code 'in case something happens'.

Since all the changes are saved in Git anyway I proposed to finally get rid of all unused files. My idea was only partially accepted with a suggestion to place everything into `backup` subdirectories reason being that it is 'quicker and easier to recover an old working version this way'.

But does that make sense?
Could somebody comment and/or reference some applicable Git workflows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete it. Since it's under version control, you can recover it at any time. Keeping code that does no useful work is just a maintenance cost to pay for you and your team.

See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103031/should-i-remove-unreferenced-code) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699995/why-unused-code-should-be-deleted) or [this blog post](http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2013/04/dead-code-is-rotting-your-codebase/).

EDIT: People often talk about commented out code, like [here](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/please-don-t-commit-commented-out-code-53d0b5b26d5f) or  [here](http://blog.agilistic.nl/agile-book-essentials-1-clean-code-by-robert-c-martin1/):

> Don’t comment out code; remove it. The problem here is that it’s very
>   tempting never to remove old code, perhaps out of fear to lose it.
>   Other developers may not understand why code was commented out, and
>   leave it there. [...]

But everything said about that also applies to files containing old code, like in your case. Having a file containing unused code is even worse in my oppinion, since it's easier to forget than a commented out code block you stumble upon from time to time.